# FindOne Like not working in node js and mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am making a small chat app. This is my db connection

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
    mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/cofChat" , function(err){
        if(err)
        {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("Connected Successfully");
        }
    });
var chatSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        senderId:String,
        recieverId:String,
        message:String,
        date:{type:Date , default:Date.now}
    });
var Chat = mongoose.model("Message" , chatSchema);
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    userId: String,
    name:String ,
    image:String
});
var Users = mongoose.model("chatUsers" , userSchema);
```

And this is my function that searches for the users.

```
searchUsers:function(search)
{
    Users.findOne({name: '{'$regex': search}}, function(err,obj) { console.log(obj); });
}
```

But it returns me undefined. Any ideas what have I done wrong?

Comment: First check your spelling '{'$regex' doesn't look right.. maybe like this {'$regex'. Also check if regular expression is valid. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/  Hope this helps.

Comment: any err ? console log err object as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
Users.findOne({name: {$regex: search}}
```

Try this:

```
Users.findOne({name: {$regex: search, $options: 'ig'}}
```

> i: insensitive, &
> g: global

See, if that works!